# Let S ⊂ R 2 . Show that if cl(S) is convex, then S is convex.

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis

Let $S ⊂ R^2$. 
 Show that if $cl(S)$ is convex, then S is convex.
This seems intuitive but, I am having trouble thinking of a proof or counter example.

Comment: This is a false statement. Think of the square with a boundary point removed.

Comment: Let $D=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\}$, and let $S=D\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$.

Comment: okay this makes so much sense, and why I could not wrap my head around it, I knew it is true for the other way around (if a set is convex then the closure of the set is convex so I was confused) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true.  For example, let $S$ be the union of the open interval from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and the open interval from $(1,0)$ to $(2,0)$.

Then $S$ is not convex but its closure, the closed interval from $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$, is convex.

A similar example works in any $\Bbb R^n$, even for $n=1$.

Comment: thanks! this makes much more sense